# jersey client selected response

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am using below code for fetching employees from the restful webservice .
The employee have a field call status (active, in-active). The below code is returning all the employees but I want only active employees.

Is it possible to get all the employees which has status as 'active' .

I don't want to load all the employees in my employee list . I want only active employee should be returned in response list.

Here:  Employee is my Bean class mapped to the response XML.

```
   ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getFeatures().put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", Boolean.TRUE);
                Client c = Client.create(clientConfig);
                WebResource r = c.resource("https://ww.abcd.com/rest/employees?pagenumber=1&perpage=6000");
    List<Employee> employeeList = r.accept(
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).
                    header("Authorization", "some token").
                    get(new GenericType<List<Employee>>() {});
```

Comment: Why don't you try running your code instead of wasting your and our time asking us if it will work?

Comment: The code I pasted is returning all the employees . do you know any solution to get only employees which are having status as 'active' ??

Comment: My suggestion would be to write an api on the server side to return employees that are active

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't own the server side.